# Oracle - Validate user and password without opening another connection?

Tags: oracle, connection-pooling

Is there some function/procedure/package that validates a username and password in `Oracle` (from a user that exists in the db)?

**Background**: We want to create a web application that will use a pool of connections. All users already exists in the database, because of a legacy 6i application. So we think that the best approach is to validate the user and password of the database, but we don't want to hardcode the url and open a new connection just to validate this.

I know that another way is to store a password in a user's table, but if the Oracle provide this option will be much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out a [unofficial script](http://www.petefinnigan.com/testpwd.sql) that verify the Oracle's `user$` table.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should look into Proxy Users. They are specifically designed to have end-users authenticate against the database in a 3-tier architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I understood correctly, the password provided to the database will be the same of the data source configured and not the password of the end user that I'm trying to validate.

Answer (score 1):

We use LDAP for app level authentication.

Comment: Yes, LDAP is another good solution. But i'm still wondering if the functionality exists in Oracle. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will work.

1. You alread stated that Proxy Users don't work for your purpose
2. Tom Kyte says it doesn't work. And normally Tom Kyte is right about anything Oracle http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:73704414259631 although that thread is pretty old ...